# How to get IcedTea browser plugin (OpenJDK browser java plugin) for windows?

Tags: java, java-web-start, icedtea, azul-zulu

Is IcedTea's Java browser plugin (OpenJDK browser java plugin) for windows available?

I googled, but couldn't find any windows installer for the same.

I tried Zulu, but it seems zulu is not providing browser plugin for Java.

Answer (score 1):

IcedTea-Web devs provide binary builds at http://icedtea.wildebeest.org/download/icedtea-web-binaries. Click on the lastest version you can see, go to `windows` and there will be MSI and ZIP builds. It works well with Zulu 8(u202) for Windows from my experience, and their wiki article seems to suggest that it does work for later versions of Java (form which Oracle removed JWS).

If you are using the MSI build, the program should install to `C:\Program Files\IcedTeaWeb\WebStart\bin`. Go there and you can see `javaws.exe` (or a `.bat`), basically the `javaws` command you see elsewhere. Have it open a file with `javaws --jnlp FILE`, or `javaws FILE`. You should be able to associate it to the JNLP file type manually.

For other things to do including the config, see https://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/IcedTea-Web#End_Users.

---

If you are looking for a bundled installer for enterprise use, [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) is planning on [putting ITW in their bundle](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-installer/issues/22). For now just do it with an extra MSI file.